# Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got this error. I looked through the answers posted previously but still I have the same problem.

index.html

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="customersApp">
<head>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.html">

    <title>Vizavoo</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!--external css-->
   <link href="css/slidebars.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />


</head>

  <body>

   <div ng-view></div>



    <!-- js placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
       <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script> 
       <script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
         <script src="app/app.js"></script>
         <script src="app/controllers/loginController.js"> </script>
           <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



  </body>

<!-- Mirrored from thevectorlab.net/flatlab/login.html by HTTrack Website Copier/3.x [XR&CO'2014], Mon, 08 Dec 2014 06:09:06 GMT -->
</html>
```

app.js

```
(function(){

var app= angular.module('customersApp',['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/login', {
            title: 'Login',
            controller: 'loginController',
               templateUrl: 'app/views/loginuser.html'
        })
            .when('/logout', {
                title: 'Logout',
                templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
                controller: 'loginController'
            })

            .when('/dashboard', {
                title: 'Dashboard',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/dynamic_table.html',
                controller: 'loginController'
            })
            .when('/signup', {
                title: 'Signup',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/registration.html',
                controller: 'loginController'
            })

            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/login'
            });
  }]);

}());
```

loginController.js

```
app.controller('loginController', function ($scope,$http, Data) {
    //initially set those objects to null to avoid undefined error
    $scope.login = {};
    $scope.signup = {};
    $scope.doLogin = function (customer) {


        $.post("http://dev.miniluxe.com:4002/email_login",
  {

     email : $scope.login.email,
      password : $scope.login.password
  },
  function(data,status){


      data = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(data);

      if(data.log==1)
      {

          // window.location.href = "dashboard";
           $location.path('dashboard');
      }
      else
      {


         alert("wrong username and password");
      }


  });


    };

    $scope.logout = function () {
        Data.get('logout').then(function (results) {
            Data.toast(results);
            $location.path('login');
        });
    }
    app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        if(input) {
            start = +start; //parse to int
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
    }
});






});
```

Please check the code and tell me where I am making a mistake.

Comment: Why are you wrapping your app.js code in an anonymous function?

Comment: I read the course of Dan wahlin....they have done like that so i follow their method

Comment: That isn't required. Doing that is limiting scope of variable `app` only to that function and you are trying to use that in another file. Just remove that anonymous function and it will run.

Comment: thanks, problem was solved but shows an another Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: DataProvider <- Data

Comment: I've given that in my answer below, please remove `Data` dependency from your controller dependency injections. There are more things to fix in your code. So look at my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a good lesson on scope. Wrapping things in anonymous functions (`function(){...}());`) will make variables declared inside that function invisible to things outside the function. I wont go over all the javascript scope stuff in this response because it is well [documented on many other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript) but essentially this is your problem;

```
(function(){
    var hello = "world";
}());
console.log(hello); // no good, hello is not declared in this scope
```

In short remove the anonymous function that's in your `app.js` or declare the `app` variable outside the function.

Answer (score 12):

It looks like all other answers are from people with no knowledge of Angular JS, and only of Javascript. They all give the same erroneous answer, which may cause the code to work, but introduce a bad practice.

Wrapping your code in an anonymous function is fine!

This is not the problem. The problem is that you put your controller in a separate file, but forgot to put it in a separate module as well.

loginController.js

```
angular.module('customersApp.loginController',[])

.controller('loginController', function ($scope,$http, Data) {
  ...
});
```

app.js

```
var app= angular.module('customersApp',['ngRoute','customersApp.loginController']);
```

This answer is backed up by the angular seed project that is also referred to in the official angular docs: https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

Comment: Putting the controller in a separate file with the same module is fine (as long as they are related).  The code provided by the OP will create an `Uncaught ReferenceError` because `app` variable is out of scope.

Comment: Doing this unnecessarily obscures your code so should be considered a bad practice. There is also nothing that hints to the idea that this was a deliberate design choice by OP.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same error. In my case it was the order of the javascript files.

I had to make sure app.js was declared before the service.js file (the file that had a reference to app in it).

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Service.js"></script>
```

In addition, this error ("app is not defined") could be caused by a syntax error in your javascript code, so check your javascript code for syntax errors, if there is a "Uncaught SyntaxError" paired up with it.

Answer (score 2):

your app is defined inside anonymous function , so app has the scope within it. try creating a global app variable.

```
(function(){

 app= angular.module('customersApp',['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/login', {
            title: 'Login',
            controller: 'loginController',
               templateUrl: 'app/views/loginuser.html'
        })
            .when('/logout', {
                title: 'Logout',
                templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
                controller: 'loginController'
            })

            .when('/dashboard', {
                title: 'Dashboard',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/dynamic_table.html',
                controller: 'loginController'
            })
            .when('/signup', {
                title: 'Signup',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/registration.html',
                controller: 'loginController'
            })

            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/login'
            });
  }]);

}());
```

Comment: helped, global in index.js. I am using browserify, so cannot eliminate any anonymous functions. Browserify adds them anyway

Answer (score 2):

Remove the anonymous function from app.js like:

```
var app= angular.module('customersApp',['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
        // rest of the code
  }]);
```

And also move your `startFrom` filter registration code out of the controller block. One last thing that your controller is accepting an dependency injection at very last: `Data` which is not defined, so remove that also.

Hope this helps!